# Does Transact SQL support ENABLE/DISABLE TRIGGER statement ? I am having an "incorrect syntax" error near those statements inside my T-SQL code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, ssms

Here is the Transact SQL code I am trying to execute inside SSMS :

```
USE DB_TEST
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRY
    Declare  @code_ser INT;
select @code_ser = code_serv from SERVICE where code_serv > 200

IF( @code_ser = 201 )
BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE sec
        ADD [num_city] [nvarchar](3) not NULL default '01'
          
         DISABLE TRIGGER dbo.sec_log_trig ON sec
          

        update sec set  num_cf='01'
          
         ENABLE TRIGGER dbo.sec_log_trig ON sec
        

         
        ALTER TABLE pub
        ADD [num_city] [nvarchar](3) not NULL default '01'
         
         
        DISABLE TRIGGER dbo.pub_log_trig ON pub
        
        update pub set num_city='01'
         
        ENABLE TRIGGER dbo.pub_log_trig ON pub
        
END 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

    IF( @@TRANCOUNT > 0)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH;

IF( @@TRANCOUNT > 0)
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

When I execute the code, I get many errors like this one :
*Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line x*
With the line numbers pointing where ENABLE TRIGGER and DISABLE TRIGGER are.

What is wrong with my code ? Does T-SQL permit using ENABLE and DISABLE TRIGGER statements inside its code ?

Comment: Why do you need to do those `UPDATE` statements anyway? You add the column with `NOT NULL` meaning a `DEFAULT` value *must* be supplied; you do this so all the rows will have the `DEFAULT` value. The `UPDATE` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Larnu what about the values for that column before adding it ? aren't they supposed to contain NULL values after adding the new column ? I want them to have the default value too

Comment: *"what about the values for that column before adding it ?"* How can a column that doesn't exist have a value..? *"aren't they supposed to contain NULL values after adding the new column ?"* A `NOT NULL` column ***CANNOT*** contain `NULL`; that's the whole point of `NOT NULL`. If you did not supply a `DEFAULT` value, the `ALTER` statement would fail.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice the NOT NULL on the ADD COLUMN since this is legacy code I am working on, thanks for the remarks

Comment: If you didn't have `NOT NULL` you could add `WITH VALUES` into the statement, which would populate the column with the `DEFAULT` value, rather than `NULL`.

Comment: Do NOT catch errors if you do not do anything with them. Do NOT catch errors only to convert them into a resultset. Exception handling by the caller relies on the **exception** to be raised. A resultset <> an exception that can be caught.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
    ALTER TABLE sec
    ADD [num_city] [nvarchar](3) not NULL default '01'
      
     DISABLE TRIGGER dbo.sec_log_trig ON sec
```

do this

```
    ALTER TABLE sec
    ADD [num_city] [nvarchar](3) not NULL default '01';
      
     DISABLE TRIGGER dbo.sec_log_trig ON sec
```

Notice the ";"  after the ALTER statement

Comment: Alternatively (if your `;` key is broken) you can also do this:
`ALTER TABLE sec ADD [num_city] [nvarchar](3) not NULL default '01'
ALTER TABLE sec DISABLE TRIGGER sec_log_trig`

Comment: Thank you @Glanchez, I eventually discovered that I did not need those triggers disabled and enabled, Larnu pointed that on the comments section under the question